# My image isn't scaling as I expect inside an image carousel when I change window size

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, grid

I want my images in an image carousel to scale when I change the size of the window. If I add the following to the CSS,

```
.carousel-slide img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

then for some reason I think the browser is taking the `div class="carousel-slide"` as the parent of the img instead of the figure, and I get all 4 images displaying in the width of the figure. Or perhaps it is because I am using the CSS Grid? How do I fix this behaviour?

HTML:

```
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="image-carousel">
            <button id="leftButton">
                PREV
            </button>
            <div id="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-slide">
                    <figure> 
                        <img id="lastClone" src="image-4.jpg" alt=""> 
                        <br>
                        <figcaption>
                            figcap1
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure> 
                        <img src="image-1.jpg" alt="">
                        <br>
                        <figcaption>
                            figcap2
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure> 
                        <img src="image-4.jpg" alt=""> 
                        <br>
                        <figcaption>
                            figcap4 
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure> 
                        <img id="firstClone" src="image-1.jpg" alt="">
                        <br>
                        <figcaption>
                            figcap5
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="rightButton">
                NEXT
            </button> 
        </section> 
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#image-carousel{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        ". leftButton carousel rightButton .";  
    grid-template-columns: 0.4fr 0.5fr 60vw 0.5fr 0.4fr; 
    grid-template-rows: auto;
}
#carousel{
    grid-area: carousel;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-slide{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
}
.carousel-slide img{
    z-index: 1; 
    /*width: 100%;  this is treating carousel-slide as parent instead of figure? why?*/
}
.carousel-slide figure{
    width: 100%;
}
#leftButton{
    grid-area: leftButton;
    z-index: 3;
}
#rightButton{
    grid-area: rightButton;
    z-index: 3;
}
#carousel figcaption{
    background-color: rgba(15, 27, 27, 0.7);  
    text-align: center;

    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Welcome, please create a demo (on snippet or fiddle) to show a live example